# What to consider when choosing version of Python?

Tags: python

I will be giving a small course on the Python programming language to a group of interns this summer. As I am sure you know, there are many different versions of the Python language.

I am wondering what to consider when choosing a particular version of the Python programming language. Is choosing the latest version of Python *always* the correct decision?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A few years ago, the answer to this would have been "stick with Python 2; the libraries aren't ready for Python 3 yet". In many cases, that would have been a deal-breaker, because many of the older libraries were pretty useful, particularly for [scientific computation](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/01/03/will-scientists-ever-move-to-python-3/).

However, the story's a bit different now, in 2017. [There isn't much of a reason to stick with Python 2](http://py3readiness.org/); almost all of the top 360 libraries support it now.

A few popular resources, like [Learn Python the Hard Way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book), have remained ardently Python 2-only [until recently](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/) (early 2017), and I suspect a lot of old tutorials haven't been updated.

If you stay with Python 2, you miss out on all of the really nice features, like `async` and f-strings, which have only been added to the 3.x series.

Something to consider, though: Python 2 and 3 are very similar, and learning one will mean you can relatively easily switch to the other. Python 3 just removes the major 'gotchas', like `5 / 2 = 2`, or bad things happening when you use Unicode. For beginners, I think it's a great advantage for things to work intuitively (until, of course, you fight with the [floating point representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618943/why-does-the-floating-point-value-of-40-1-look-nice-in-python-3-but-30-1-doesn) issue).

Generally, I don't think you'll experience any problems with Python 3, and it seems logical to me to learn the *future* of the language, rather than Python 2, [which is legacy](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3).

Comment: Second this. Used to use Python 2 because Pygame wasn't available for 3. Now that it is, no reason to look back.

Comment: The only reason to look into Python 2 is if you are working with some library or package that is created in it.  Otherwise, I 100% agree with @Aurora001

Comment: at this time web mining libraries like pattern (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pattern) still stick with python2. Their py3 version still at testing stage

Comment: Also keep in mind that -as noted in [PEP-373](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/)- in [2020](https://pythonclock.org/) Python 2.X will be retired...